# Эквивалент var_dump() в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Только начал учить JavaScript, и поэтому задам, пожалуй, смешной вопрос.

Есть ли в JavaScript `var_dump`, такой, как в php. Чтобы можно было посмотреть тип переменной, и если это массив, то просмотреть его содержание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В JavaScript есть оператор typeof, служащий для определения типа значения (значения могут быть не только в переменных, значения могут существовать сами по себе).

```
typeof 123; // "number"
typeof ""; // "string" 
typeof true; // "boolean"
typeof undefined; // "undefined"
```

А вот дальше нас ждут сюрпризы:

```
typeof /\s/; // "object"
typeof null; // "object"
typeof []; // "object"
typeof new String(); // "object"
typeof NaN; // "number"
```

Поэтому пользоваться оператором typeof для определения типа переменной не стоит. Есть много других способов, один из самых лучших по моему мнению это предложенный Ангусом Кроллом:

```
var toType = function(obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}
```

Если нужны подробности, то [вот](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/) его статья.

Answer (score 11):

Одна из распостранённых практик: разрабатывать в [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/) с подключённым дополнением [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (если ещё не знаете, что оно умеет, обрадуетесь — незаменимый инструмент для веб-разработки).

С таким арсеналом, фунция `console.log( mojObject );` выведет и объект, и любые другие типы JS данных в удобном виде в консоль Firebug'а.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам поможет [ссылка](http://zlob.in/2013/01/analog-phpshnoj-funkcii-var_dump-v-javascript/), и еще [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603987/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-var-dump-or-print-r-in-php)

Если, Вам, необходимо просмотреть тип переменной, то оператор [typeof](http://javascript.ru/typeof)

И по поводу смешного вопроса:  "И мы тоже не с этого начинали, а все в мастера вышли" :)